# Add to textfile doesn't work

Tags: php, text-files

I have created a small script to add a string to a text file, but it does not seem to work.

```
<?php
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $city = $_POST["city"];
    // Concatenate all values into one string.
    $subscription = strtolower(trim($email)) . "," . ucwords(trim($name)) . "," .  ucwords(trim($city));
    $file = "21_nieuwsbrief.txt";
    file_put_contents($file, (string)$subscription, FILE_APPEND);
    echo $subscription;
?>
```

When testing this on the server, the `echo $subscription` shows the correct output.

But when I go to `21_nieuwsbrief.txt`, it does not show any lines of text.

Could someone help me out here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should add a newline to `$subscription` when you're writing to the file, so you don't get all the subscriptions on the same line.

Comment: Why do you think you need to cast `$subscription` to a string? It's already a string.

Comment: Turn on error reporting: `error_reporting(E_ALL)`. Maybe it's getting an error writing to the file.

Comment: Problem is not in this code. This code working in my machine.

Comment: Do you keep this *file open* during the script running?? @Johan

Comment: I have tried a couple of things, but I can't seem to get it to work. However I found another post somewhere online that I might not have the proper write access to the file.